# Regex: Capture an overlapping pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

I would want to capture all combinations of my pattern even if it is overlapped.

**Sample text**

> pack my box 12345 pack my box 67890 blah blah far away another pack my box 99999 is present

**Expected output**

```
Match 1 - pack my box 12345 pack my
Match 2 - pack my box 67890 blah bl
Match 3 - pack my box 99999 is pres
```

**Regex**

> /pack my box.{0,14}/

However, `Match 2` is not outputted since it is overlapping with 1.

[image]

Obviously, this is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of a bigger problem.

Answer (score -1):

Found out the answer (referenced from the duplicate post)

`(?=(pack my box.{0,14}))`

[image]

Comment: It would work for `scan`, but would not work for `gsub`. The matches are actually empty.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. I was actually looking for a solution for `scan`. Good to know that it will not work `gsub`